# Dirac delta question from “Classical covariant fields” by Burgess

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry

If you have the book with you. Kindly tell me how did he reach equation 2.54 from equation 2.52. I tried to solve the delta function according to given instruction but I am making some mistake. Kindly help.

> $$\begin{align}
> A_\mu(x) &= \int\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n+1}k}{(2\pi)^{n+1}}e^{ik_\mu x^\mu} A_{\mu}(k)\delta(k^2),\tag{2.52} \\
> \hline
> A_\mu(x) &= \hat{\epsilon}_\mu\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n+1}k}{(2\pi)^{n+1}}e^{i(k_i x^i - \omega t)}A(k)\frac{1}{c k_i}\biggl(\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k^i}\biggr) \\
> &\qquad\times\Bigl(\delta(k_0 - \sqrt{\mathbf{k}^2}) + \delta(k_0 + \sqrt{\mathbf{k}^2})\Bigr).\tag{2.54}
> \end{align}$$

Using

> $$\delta(g(x)) = \sum_i \frac{1}{g'(x_i)}\delta(g(x_i)),\tag{A.15}$$

Comment: Would you be so kind, to formulate the question here in your own words? Or at least give a quote? Make it easy for people to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $k^2=\mathbf{k}^2-k_0^2=-(k_0-\sqrt{\mathbf{k^2}})(k_0+\sqrt{\mathbf{k^2}})$. Note that $\delta$ doesn't care about the minus sign. (A.15) however, is wrong, it should say: $$ \delta(g(x))=\sum_{\{x_i |g(x_i)=0\}} \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|}. $$
Now $\delta(k^2)=\delta\big((k_0-\sqrt{\mathbf{k^2}})(k_0+\sqrt{\mathbf{k^2}})\big)$, and since $g=k_0^2-k_ik^i=(\omega/c)^2-k_ik^i$, $g'=\frac{\partial g}{\partial k^{\mu}}\frac{\partial k^{\mu}}{\partial k_0}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial k^{i}}\frac{\partial k^{i}}{\partial k_0}=k_i\frac{\partial k^{i}}{\partial (\omega/c)}$. This implies that $\delta(k^2)=\frac{1}{ck_i}\frac{\partial{\omega}}{\partial{k^i}}\Big(\delta(k_0-\sqrt{\mathbf{k^2}})+\delta(k_0+\sqrt{\mathbf{k^2}})\Big)$. And, I assume that $A_{\mu}(k)\equiv A(k)\hat \epsilon_{\mu}$, so that (2.54) does indeed follow from (2.52). I hope this helps!

Comment: thanx a lot. its so nice of you...